# Laravel Sending from data to database

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.2 and i am curently developing a messaging system for my app. i am trying to send messages to the database, but i keep getting this error "**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::messages()**"
My MessageController is as Follows:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Message;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function CreateMessage(Request $request)
    {

        $meso = new Message();
        $meso->body = $request['body'];
        $meso->subject = $request['subject'];


        $request->user()->messages()->save($meso) ;


       return redirect()->route('mail');
    }
}
```

Here is my routes file

```
Route::post('send', 'MessageController@CreateMessage');
```

and here is my form:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ url('/send') }}">
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">To</label>
                                                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                      <input type="text" placeholder="" id="inputEmail1" class="form-control">
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Cc / Bcc</label>
                                                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                      <input type="text" placeholder="" id="cc" class="form-control">
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                                                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                      <input type="text" placeholder="" id="inputPassword1" class="form-control">
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
                                                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                      <textarea rows="10" cols="30" class="form-control" id="" name=""></textarea>
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>

                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                  <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                                      <span class="btn green fileinput-button">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-plus fa fa-white"></i>
                                                        <span>Attachment</span>
                                                        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="">
                                                      </span>
                                                      <button class="btn btn-send" type="submit">Send</button>
                                                      <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
                                          </form>
```

Someone help me debug this error

Comment: show your User model and message model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create `messages()` relationship in `User` model:

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
}
```

Also, you need to have `user_id` [foreign key defined](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) in `messages` table to make the relationship work.

Comment: it now giives me "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()" error

Comment: yeea it sends the values to the database, but it shows "Route [mail] not defined.".. ?? why??

Comment: @SirGeorge it's not related to the original question and to be able to help you I need to see appropriate code which is trying to use `mail` route and route definition itself. Please tick my answer, create another question and post the code so we'll be able to help you with a new problem. That's how SO works. )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$request->user()->messages->save($meso);
```

instead of:

```
$request->user()->messages()->save($meso);
```

Comment: this is what i get after the changes you told me "Call to a member function save() on null"

Comment: user mode:<?php

namespace App;
use Auth;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function messages()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Message');
}
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * 
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * 
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}

Comment: message model:<?php

namespace App;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Message extends Model
{
   public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Message');
    }


}

Comment: my values are saved correctly to the database, but then i get an error page "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:". when i check my table, there are values in it, but an error page is shown in the front end